# MacKeeper window keeps popping up in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I keep getting a MacKeeper ad popping up in Google Chrome.  I don't see any extensions listed that may cause this.  How can I find the cause for this and eliminate it?

Comment: Please add a screenshot.

Comment: Is it safe to assume you are using Mac OS X?

Comment: Yes, Mac OS X 10.7.3.